# .NET Regex for parsing chess moves

Tags: c#, regex

**Background**

I'd like to parse quite a few of strings representing chess moves:

```
1.e4e62.d3d53.Nd2c54.g3Nf6
```

Each move begins with an increasing number 1., 2., 3. etc. There are no spaces in-between the moves.

The perfect match would be an array like this:

```
["1.e4e6", "2.d3d5", "3.Nd2c5", "4.g3Nf6"]
```

**Regex Question**

My regex so far is:

```
([0-9]\.)(.*?)(?=[0-9]\.)
```

This works in an online .NET Regex Tester (Regex Storm), apart not including the last move (4th). 
How to include the last one too?

**C# Question**

My code is:

```
var regex = new Regex(@"([0-9]\.)(.*?)(?=[0-9]\.)");
var match = regex.Match(game);
```

The match here includes only one entry "1.e4e6" and not three (or four).
How to fix?

Thanks,
pom

Comment: Take another look at the `Regex` documentation. You will never get more than one result with [`Match`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.match?view=netframework-4.8); you want [`Matches`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.matches?view=netframework-4.8).

Comment: When you say "Each move begins with an increasing digit" - you're implying that there are only 9 possible moves in chess. Do you not mean "number"?

Comment: @Herohtar: ok, that's a good tip!  at Enumativity: Sure, I mean number :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can not match the last item because the lookahead assertion is not true as there is no digit and dot following.

You can add to match the end of the string using an alternation.

To get all the results you could use [Matches](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.matches?view=netframework-4.8) instead.

```
([0-9]\.)(.*?)(?=[0-9]\.|$)
```

[Regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%5b0-9%5d%5c.%29%28.*%3f%29%28%3f%3d%5b0-9%5d%5c.%7c%24%29&i=1.e4e62.d3d53.Nd2c54.g3Nf6) | [C# demo](https://ideone.com/NQ2x3i)

For example

```
string pattern = @"([0-9]\.)(.*?)(?=[0-9]\.|$)";
string input = @"1.e4e62.d3d53.Nd2c54.g3Nf6";

foreach (Match m in Regex.Matches(input, pattern))
{
    Console.WriteLine(m.Value);
}
```

Note that if you want to get a match only and don't want to match spaces, you can use `\S` instead of a `.` and omit the capturing group:

```
[0-9]\.\S*?(?=[0-9]\.|$)
```

[Regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5b0-9%5d%5c.%5cS*%3f%28%3f%3d%5b0-9%5d%5c.%7c%24%29&i=1.e4e62.d3d53.Nd2c54.g3Nf6)

Comment: Great, the first option works for me fine in the online tester. Do you have an idea for the C# question as well? Somehow my C# code doesn't work...

Comment: @Pompair You have to use [Matches](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.matches?view=netframework-4.8) to get all the results.

Comment: @erikkallen For the example data, if the N can only occur once I think the OP might use an alternation `(?:\d+\.[a-h]\dN?[a-h]\d|\d+\.N[a-h]\d[a-h]\d)` See a [demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3f%3a%5cd%2b%5c.%5ba-h%5d%5cdN%3f%5ba-h%5d%5cd%7c%5cd%2b%5c.N%5ba-h%5d%5cd%5ba-h%5d%5cd%29&i=1.e4e62.d3d53.Nd2c54.g3Nf65.g3Nf66.g3Nf67.g3Nf68.g3Nf69.g3Nf610.g3Nf611.g3Nf612.Nd2c5%0d%0a)